# Get field names from Scala case class with specific annotation

Tags: scala, reflection, annotations

```
final class ContactInfo extends StaticAnnotation{}

case class Person(val id: String,
              val firstName: String,
              val lastName: String,
              @ContactInfo val phoneNumbers: Seq[String],
              @ContactInfo val email: String)

def getContactInfoFields[T: TypeTag]: Seq[String] = {
???
}
```

Expected output getContactInfoFields[Person] = ("phoneNumbers", "email")

[Riffing off the answer to a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792383/how-to-list-all-fields-with-a-custom-annotation-using-scalas-reflection-at-runt) I've tried

```
def getContactInfoFields[T: TypeTag]: Seq[String] = {
  val fields = typeOf[T].members.collect{ case s: TermSymbol => s }.
    filter(s => s.isVal || s.isVar)

  fields.filter(_.annotations.exists(_.isInstanceOf[ContactInfo]))
    .map(x=>x.name.toString).toSeq
}
```

However in practice this is returning an empty sequence.  What am I missing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? In Scala you can actually access the fields *and* their names at compile time and use them to e.g. generate some CSV/XML/JSON or something else. If you give us more information about the problem domain we can help better. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could represent this information at the type level.

```
sealed trait ContactInfo
case class PhoneNumbers(numbers: Seq[String]) extends ContactInfo
case class Email(email: String) extends ContactInfo

case class Person(id: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, phoneNumbers: PhoneNumbers, email: Email)

def contactInfo[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].members.filter(!_.isMethod).map(_.typeSignature).collect {
  case t if t <:< typeOf[ContactInfo] => t.typeSymbol.name.toString
}
```

Calling `contactInfo[Person]` returns `Iterable[String] = List(Email, PhoneNumbers)`

Comment: That seems sound, however the data contract with the client is set for now and the deserialization of that Person object would no longer be as expected

    {
      "id":"asdfasdf",
      "firstName": "bob",
      "phoneNumbers":["333", "444"],
      "email":"333@null.com"
    }

would now be

    {
      "id":"asdfasdf",
      "firstName": "bob",
      "phoneNumbers":{numbers:["333", "444"]},
      "email":{"email":"333@null.com"}
    }

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for all your help!  I've managed to come up with a working solution.  As it turns out I was trying to compare JavaUniverse.reflection.Types to Scala Universe reflections types which is why the filter statement was failing.  The below function returns as expected

```
def listContactInfoFields(symbol: TypeSymbol): Seq[String] = {

  val terms = symbol.asClass.primaryConstructor.typeSignature.paramLists.head

  val annotatedFields = terms.filter(_.annotations.exists(_.tree.tpe =:= typeOf[ContactInfo]))

  annotatedFields.map(_.name.toString)
}
```

Comment: how did you call this method ?